# How to call a method in the wcf service object without going through the WCF runtime stack?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a scenario where I have hosted a wcf service in a C# application and this application also has some logic which would call one method of the Wcf service via the Proxy.

Since the Wcf service and the application logic is present in the same app domain, is there any way that i can call that one service method directly as if i am calling the method if present in a referenced dll ?

Comment: Have you tried just reference the wcf dll? In my opinion it should work if both applications have acces to this same GAC

Answer (score 0):

What InstanceContextMode are you using for your WCF service? If it is not Singleton then you are free simply to create an instance of the service by hand and then use that directly in your application.

As general advice, to reduce coupling on WCF, it is often better to use a Service Facade in WCF which is merely a facade onto your underlying service (which has no dependencies on WCF so can be easily reused).